# How to get the HTML of a webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to implement a chrome extension, part of which would involve the user putting a URL in a text area and the extension promptly getting the HTML of the website and parsing the information.

I'm, however, unable to implement scraping the HTML from the different website, and hence was wondering if there was a way actually to download the HTML using Javascript.

I tried using `fetch` and `XMLHTTPRequest` and they didn't work because CORS policy. How else would I fetch the webpage?

Comment: Unless the website is pure HTML without JS amending the DOM this won't be particularly effective. You would probably have to set up a server that scrapes the site with something like Playwright or Puppeteer, and then call an endpoint with your extension which sends the full page.

Comment: If I wanted to deploy the extension, how would I make sure that the server is also deployed? Just curious to see how I should move forward with my project